# Perl: An asynchronous http proxy via mojolicious

Tags: perl, asynchronous, http-proxy, mojolicious

I made a simple http proxy, it's work fine, but not fast, because in the function handle_request, I use

```
my $tx = $ua->start( Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req=>$request) );
```

to do the request, it's blocking.

I try to use a callback like:

```
$ua->start( Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req=>$request) )=>sub{ ... }
```

to make it's non-blocking, and then, got a mistake:

```
'error' => { 'message' => 'Premature connection close'}
```

I guess that's because function `handle_request` return immediately, it does not wait the callback to be finished. If I use semaphore to wait the callback, that's mean it's blocking again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Mojo::IOLoop::Server;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::Message::Response;
use Mojo::Message::Request;
use Mojo::Transaction::HTTP;
use Data::Dumper;

binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";

my %buffer;

Mojo::IOLoop->server( {port => 3128} => sub {
    my ($loop, $stream, $client) = @_;

    $stream->on(
        read => sub {
            my ($stream, $chunk) = @_;

            my $buffer = $buffer{$client}{read_buffer} .= $chunk;

            if ($buffer =~ /^GET\s+|POST\s+|HEAD\s+(.*)\r\n\r\n$/i) {
                $buffer{$client}{read_buffer} = '';
                &handle_request($client,$stream,$buffer);
            }

            elsif ($buffer =~ /^CONNECT\s+(.*)\r\n\r\n$/i) {
                $buffer{$client}{read_buffer} = '';
                &handle_connect($stream,$buffer);
            }

            elsif($buffer{$client}{connection})
            {
                $buffer{$client}{read_buffer} = '';
                Mojo::IOLoop->stream($buffer{$client}{connection})->write($chunk);
            }

            if(length($buffer)>= 20 *1024 * 1024) {
                delete $buffer{$client};
                Mojo::IOLoop->remove($client);
                return;
            }
        });
});

sub handle_request{

    my($client,$stream,$chunk) = @_;

    my $request = Mojo::Message::Request->new;
    $request = $request->parse($chunk);

    my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    my $tx = $ua->start( Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req=>$request) );

    $stream->write( $tx->res->to_string );
}

sub handle_connect{
    my ($stream, $chunk) = @_;
    my $request = Mojo::Message::Request->new;
    my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

    $request = $request->parse($chunk);

    print Dumper($request);
}

Mojo::IOLoop->start;
```

Hope to get some suggestions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problem:

1. You try to call nonblocking variant of `$ua->start` when your code have blocking style. Function `handle_request` must have callback as parameter.
   If you have chain of callback then the best way to implement it is to use  `Mojo::IOLoop::Delay`.
2. When you create variable $ua in non-blocking style in sub `handle_request` then your variable is destoyed by garbage collector because first execute exit of sub `handle_request` and $ua destroyed, because it is local variable and then get answer from $ua. So you get `Premature connection close`. You need to save instance of $ua elsewhere to prevent such error.

**Upd**.
I [write](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/8bdd6bd8089837bfc7c0) bad variant of http/https proxy which work only via CONNECT method and have bug with not full first http message.

**Upd**.
I add another example of http/https proxy which correctly read first http message and work not only via CONNECT method.

**Upd**.
Oh, author of the Mojo wrote [example](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/09579d3e596a0f66eb64e600f32e6a735ea9b36d/examples/connect-proxy.pl) of https proxy

Comment: Thank you very much. I store $ua in a hashtable, it's ok now. for the 1st problem, I don't know what i should do.    `my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$buffer{$client}{ua} = $ua;  
my $tx = $buffer{$client}{ua}->start( Mojo::Transaction::HTTP->new(req=>$request) =>sub {my( $ua, $tx ) = @_;$stream->write( $tx->res->to_string );} }); `